# Using custom dependency properties as DataTrigger in WPF

Tags: wpf, properties, dependencies, datatrigger

I have a custom dependency property that I would like to use as a data trigger. Here is the code behind:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BioinsulatorScannedProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "BioinsulatorScanned", 
        typeof(bool), 
        typeof(DisposablesDisplay), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

    public bool BioinsulatorScanned
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)GetValue(BioinsulatorScannedProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(BioinsulatorScannedProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

I have created a style and control template. My goal is to change the color of some text when the dependency prop is set to true...

```
<Style x:Key="TreatEye" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#d1d1d1" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
                    <Canvas>                            
                        <TextBlock x:Name="bioinsulatorText" 
                                   Canvas.Left="21" Canvas.Top="33" 
                                   Text="Bioinsulator" />
                        <TextBlock Canvas.Left="21" Canvas.Top="70" 
                                   Text="KXL Kit" />
                    </Canvas>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BioinsulatorScanned}"
                                     Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="bioinsulatorText" 
                                    Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>            
    </Style>
```

Despite successfully setting the dependency prop to true programmatically, This trigger condition never fires. This is a real pain to debug!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On which object did you define your dependency property?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly, but I'm trying to use the dependency property in the ControlTemplate.Triggers section. When it is true, I need text within "bioinsulatorText" to turn black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your dependency property is defined inside a `DisposableDisplay` object that you created. In order for the binding specified to work, an instance of that `DisposableDisplay` object must be set as the `DataContext` of the control (label in this case) or any of its ancestors.

Comment: This works perfectly. As a WPF novice, I've found data binding to be one of the most troublesome topics. In which cases does DataContext not need to be set?

Comment: `DataContext` is set by default when you use data templates. And data templates are used by default in items controls (list boxes, list views, data grids, etc.) Also, you may explicitly set the datacontext on any element to better facilitate binding. It's one of the most important concepts in WPF.

Answer (score 4):

In this case I am switching the visibility of a button using a datatrigger based on a dependency property FirstLevelProperty.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FirstLevelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FirstLevel", typeof(string), typeof(MyWindowClass));

public string FirstLevel
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetValue(FirstLevelProperty).ToString();
            }

            set
            {
                this.SetValue(FirstLevelProperty, value);
            }
        }
```

You can reference the dependency property `FirstLevel(Property)` contained (in this case) in a window by using the `RelativeSource` binding. Also you should set the default setting in the style, that will be overridden by the datatrigger.

```
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger 
             Binding="{Binding Path=FirstLevel,
             RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
             AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
             Value="SomeValue">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" 
                 Value="Hidden" />
             </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```